# VS Code live share react native?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how teamwork can be done in a live sharing vscode emulator and run as an emulator for everyone? I'm learning to see and My master is in another country

Comment: It's easier if you share your code with them using git and they run it by themselves.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try [VS Code Live Share extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack). It maybe can help you.

Comment: This does not work for react native between two devices